# AutocompleteTextView and ArrayAdapter Programmatically Crashes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code, and I am trying to link the `String [] teams` to the `team1Input` field.  The program currently crashes, I am fairly sure I am not using the `team1Input.getId()` properly.  How can I do this without touching any xml?

```
final AutoCompleteTextView team1Input = new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
        team1Input.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, team1Input.getId(), teams);
        team1Input.setAdapter(adapter);
        row1.addView(team1Input);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) state:

**textViewResourceId** The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

You're not supposed to pass the id of the TextView. The id expected is an R.layout.your_layout_here. This layout file must have only a TextView.

Comment: What if I don't want to use XML to define the layout for this AlertDialog?  The `R.id.xxx` is only for the XML stuff right?

Comment: Then consider passing 0 as the id and implementing your own custom adapter. You'll find lots of tutorials on Google.

Comment: Was this answer helpful? Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm still having issues at the moment.  Can't seem to get the custom adapter to work :/